# generating a output file by comparing the 2 files in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have 2 .txt files

```
  INPUT FILE 1:    contents of file 1(REQUEST DETAILS: RegRequest.txt):
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000001,abc@gmail.com,919876543210
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000002,abc@yahoo.com,919876543211
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000003,abc@gmail.com,919876543212


 INPUT FILE 2:  contents of file 2(RESPONSE DETAILS: RegReponse.txt):
    0000000001
    0000000003

Output file:
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000001,abc@gmail.com,919876543210,true
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000002,abc@yahoo.com,919876543211,false
    2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000003,abc@gmail.com,919876543212,true
```

The content of the input file2 tells us that which all request are success, in the above case 0000000001 and 0000000003 are success, so I have to create a output file containing the request file data and new column gets added saying whether its success or failure.
like below:
2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000001,abc@gmail.com,919876543210,`true`.

I will be getting 1 single file these 2 files are generated by executing my script but I got stuck at this point.

Here is my script I wrote to generate 2 different files as per the requirement

```
#!/bin/bash

#fetching only one file
`cat mainfile.cdr | grep -v Orig |awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
{
split($4,RegReqArr,":");
if (RegReqArr[4] == 10) { 
        split($1,dateTime,",");
        split($2,ReqidArr,":");
        gsub(/^[^<]*|;.*/,"",$8)
        split($17,MsisdnArr,":");
        print dateTime[1],ReqidArr[2],substr($8,2,length($8)-2),MsisdnArr[2] }  }' > RegRequest.txt`

`cat mainfile.cdr | grep -v Orig |awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," } 
{         
split($4,RegReqArr,":");
if (RegReqArr[4] == 11) { 
        split($2,ReqidArr,":"); 
        split($7,Response,":"); 
        if (Response[2]==200) {
                print ReqidArr[2]
        }     }  }' > RegResponse.txt`
```

After generating these 2 files RegRequest.txt and RegReponse.txt I want to generate final file like below

```
2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000001,abc@gmail.com,919876543210,true
        2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000002,abc@yahoo.com,919876543211,false
        2020-12-21 18:28:32,0000000003,abc@gmail.com,919876543212,true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  print $0,($2 in arr)?"true":"false"
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Also you are setting field separator as `|` which is not valid here because your shown samples shows you have comma separated lines, so changed it to `,` in above.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                     ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","               ##Setting field separator and output field separator as , here.
}
FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  arr[$0]                  ##Creating array arr with index of current line.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0,($2 in arr)?"true":"false"  ##Printing current line and then printing either true OR false based on 2nd field is present in arr or not.
}
' file2 file1              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Yes It worked, Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: Sir, It would be very helpful if you share me any resources from where I can understand this concepts better as I am new to shell scripting, Thanks

Comment: @mark, If you ask about awk specifically stack overflow is a huge learning database itself, you could see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK too for awk, then man page of  awk by `man awk` in your terminal will help. Once you are all set with basics then come to here and you could see questions and answers and you will understand it more, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for adding the detailed explanation it helped me understand the logic better. one quick question can we only write few entries to the file example If no need to write the reqID i.e 0000000001 in the output file(Final file)

Comment: @mark. An also you can look here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/ where you can read and download `GAWK: Effective AWK Programming: A User’s Guide for GNU Awk`. Michael Brennan, author of `mawk` has said about this book: `Thirteen years ago I wrote: “If you use AWK or want to learn how, then read this book.” True then, and still true today.`

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @ Carlos Pascual